# How to split queries in different condition and check which condition is failing the query in c#

Tags: c#, sql, split

I am writing a code in which if we put a query it will show which **`where`** clause of a query is not fetching any data in c#.

Query structure is similar to

```
select * from ABD where a=0 and b= 42 and c=(Select c from azs) or f=89 or x=10
```

Comment: What do you mean by >which "where" clause of a query<? There can only be one `WHERE` clause in a query.

Comment: It is not possible without executing the query multiple times. If multiple execution is okay, then you can execute `Any()` after each `Where()`.

Comment: after where there are multiple conditions to check. I need to verify which condition is failing the query. We can execute the sql query multiple times

Comment: It might be multiple parts **in conjunction** , that make the difference. Your program will need some type of grasp of what is what and how it is used.

Comment: `select * from ABD where a=0 and b= 42 and (c=(Select c from azs) or f=89 or x=10)` user bracket for OR condition to make it as a block and i agree with @mshsayem, check any() for each where condition

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with known queries, you can write the query to indicate which terms of the where conditions will return true or false for each row as follows:

```
select
  case when a=0 then 1 else 0 end as 'term1',
  case when b=42 then 1 else 0 end as 'term2',
  case when c=(select c from azs) then 1 else 0 end as 'term3',
  case when f=89 then 1 else 0 end as 'term4',
  case when x=10 then 1 else 0 end as 'term5'
from ABD
```

If your problem is more general in that you don't know the actual queries in advance, then you will need to write a program that can parse the input query into its individual terms. This can be done for simple scenarios by using string index-of and split, and similar, to locate the individual terms. Or can be done by implementing a simple SQL parser. I suggest that [Irony](https://github.com/IronyProject/Irony) is an excellent framework for parsers in C#, and it even includes a [SQL sample grammar](https://github.com/IronyProject/Irony/blob/master/Irony.Samples/SQL/SqlGrammar.cs).